# “Maximal” Sequences of Primes

Tags: number-theory

Are there infinitely many “maximal sequences” (my term)of primes like 11,13,17,19;101,103,107,109;191,193,197,199 in which every odd integer (except those ending in 5)are prime? In other words,every integer that “can be prime” is prime.Is this an open problem,or is it just something simple that I can’t see?

Comment: Lookup [prime quadruplets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_quadruplet) and [prime constellations](https://oeis.org/wiki/Prime_constellations).

Comment: There are almost surely infinite many such quartuples, but we do not know whether this is actually the case. The problem is open.

Comment: $$10^{19}+256116$$ is a larger example. Adding any of the digits $1,3,7,9$ results in a prime number.

Comment: An even larger example is $$10^{49}+10718757$$

Comment: If there were infinitely many such quadruplets, then there would necessarily be infinitely many twin primes, but there is no proof yet that there are infinitely many twin primes. So it's a hard problem beyond an ostensibly simpler hard problem.